# TypeError while running express()

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, http2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have used express in the past, but trying typescript for the first time. I am unsure if this error is related at all to typescript but I cannot think of anything else that could be causing the problem. I am also using WSL, but I have never had anything fail in node up to this point—though I haven't been using it very long.

This is the code that is causing the exception:

```
import { createSecureServer } from 'http2'
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
import * as express from 'express'

const key = readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/selfsigned.key')
const cert = readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/selfsigned.crt')


const server = createSecureServer({ key, cert }, express)

server.listen(3000, 'localhost', () => {
    console.log('Server is up and running!')
})
```

This is the exception:

```
TypeError: argument fn must be a function
    at Function.wrapfunction [as function] (/mnt/c/Users/caleb/Code/stats-backend/dist/app.js:4355:11)
    at populateConstructorExports (/mnt/c/Users/caleb/Code/stats-backend/dist/app.js:10346:45)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/caleb/Code/stats-backend/dist/app.js:10128:1)
    at c (/mnt/c/Users/caleb/Code/stats-backend/dist/app.js:20255:3584)
    at b.require (/mnt/c/Users/caleb/Code/stats-backend/dist/app.js:20255:3346)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/caleb/Code/stats-backend/dist/app.js:17789:19)
    at c (/mnt/c/Users/caleb/Code/stats-backend/dist/app.js:20255:3584)
    at b.require (/mnt/c/Users/caleb/Code/stats-backend/dist/app.js:20255:3346)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/caleb/Code/stats-backend/dist/app.js:7329:12)
    at c (/mnt/c/Users/caleb/Code/stats-backend/dist/app.js:20255:3584)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "4.16.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.4",
    "fuse-box": "^3.7.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.1",
    "uglify-es": "^3.3.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.16.1"
  }
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly that causing me to get this error?